# How can I pass the data collected via useRef and then pass it into a different function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-state, use-ref

I have the following return statement in my component...

```
 return (
    <StyledAlbums>
      <PageTitle>
        <h2>Albums</h2>
      </PageTitle>
      <DisplayRecords ref={drRef}>
        {albumData.map((album) => (
          <Record />
        ))}
      </DisplayRecords>
    </StyledAlbums>
  );
```

In the logic part of my component, before the return statement, how can I use the data in `drRef.current` once it has been assigned the value of the div it is referenced too? I have tried the following...

```
const getData = async () => {
    let data;
    if (drRef.current) {
      data = drRef.current;
    } else {
      data = await drRef.current;
    }
    console.log(data);
  };
```

However, this returns undefined. Also, once I have gotten hold of the referenced element, I want to pass it into a different function in my document. However, I am aware that you can't pass React Hooks to different functions. I have tried doing so by passing the data through to the function via props, but I received the error message of not being able to pass React hooks.

Altogether, my code looks like this....

```
const useWindowSize = (element) => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState([window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setSize([window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth]);
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return size;
};

const Albums = () => {
  // Set data and grab needed state

  const theme = useSelector((state) => state.theme);
  const albumData = data();
  const drRef = useRef();

  const getData = async () => {
    let data;
    if (drRef.current) {
      data = drRef.current;
    } else {
      data = await drRef.current;
    }
    console.log(data);
  };

  getData();

  return (
    <StyledAlbums>
      <PageTitle>
        <h2>Albums</h2>
      </PageTitle>
      <DisplayRecords ref={drRef}>
        {albumData.map((album) => (
          <Record />
        ))}
      </DisplayRecords>
    </StyledAlbums>
  );
};

const StyledAlbums = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 8rem - 2.8rem - 5vh - 4rem);
  position: relative;
`;
const DisplayRecords = styled.div`
  height: calc(100% - 4.7rem);
  position: relative;
  background: red;
`;

export default Albums;
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: You never assign a value to your ref, but your `await` seems to imply that you have assigned an async function to it? I have a feeling you are misunderstanding the hook.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the reference of the html element your useRef variable has been assigned to, you can use the callback function of the `ref` prop like this:

```js
const drRef = useRef();
const getNode = node => {
   // call your function here like xyz(node);
   drRef.current = node;
};

...
<DisplayRecords ref={ getNode }>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That worked with getting the node in the getNode function. The only problem I'm having now is I can't pass the hook as an argument into my useWindowSize func. Firstly it told me to make it uppercase, so I did so, and then I got another error message saying I'm breaking the rules of hooks, here's the exact error message....Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Comment: Can you show how your are using the passed hook into the `useWindowSize`? Also if your `useWindowSize` is a pure function that takes the node and gives some output, then  make a state(`useState`)  to keep track when the node is is assigned to a dom element. When that happens use a `useMemo` to call that `useWindowSize` & passing the ref to get the result.